# Creating feature templates in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, template

I am drawing points that have different tags, for example, one is a Manhole other is a Headwall. I have my symbology setup in such a way that point displays differently based on tags. Now as I am digitizing hundreds of features I dont want to tag each one of them after drawing, I want to draw the features with a default tag.

In ArcMap this can be done with feature templates. See below:

[image]

Is there a similar function in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked for, but there is an option in the settings to reuse the last entered attribute value in the QGis form, maybe this helps. You can find it under Settings-> Options->Digitizing -> Feature creation.

Comment: Thanks. This is very close but I need to switch between my tags.

Answer (score 2):

I have created "feature templates" by using the following methods which are similar to the suggestions above.
[image: qgis desktop with templates]

First you will need to duplicate the layer for as many templates you need (right click layer -> Duplicate layer) because you will be specifying a different default value for each duplicated layer.  Setup default values in the Attribute form tab.
[image: attribute form]

Then I also add a feature filter to each layer so I only see the specified feature type (Inlet, LDS, etc.)  Start editing each layer and highlight the layer you want for the feature then add a new point feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the form builder to create a value map with your options and assign one as the default

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how can one do that?